# Angle perpendicular lines and x-axis

Tags: geometry

Let's say we have a line $L$ with positive slope that intersects $(0,0)$ and makes an angle of $\theta<90^\circ$ with the $x$-axis ("on top" of the x-axis, i.e. the angle is in quadrant 1). Given a line perpendicular to $L$ going through quadrant 1, what is the angle this line forms with the x-axis?

The answer, intuitively, seems to be $90-\theta$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. To prove it just consider the right triangle formed by $x$ axis, line $L$ and the second perpendicular to $L$, then since the sum of the internal angles adds up to $180°$ the angle that the perpendicular line forms with the x-axis is $90°-\theta$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is straightforward since the axis themselves are perpendicular. It´s actually a substraction of the angle to 90 degrees and nothing else. 
Regards

Answer (score -2):

The two lines and the x-axis form a triangle. One angle is $\theta$ and one is $90^{\circ}$.

The last angle can then only be ....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1066407)

Comment: @Larry B: Correct. Are you against answering with hints?

Comment: You have not answered the question, Jens. @LarryB. is fully correct in that conclusion.  If this is what you want to call a hint, it fails miserably and is not an adequate hint to be considered an answer to the askers question.

Comment: @Amwhy: I simply don't understand you. Everyone knows the sum of a triangle's angles is 180. If 2 angles are known, so is the third.

Comment: I am @amWhy, jENS

Comment: @amWhy: Happy now? My question to you still remains unanswered.

Comment: Any time you start a mathematical sentence with "Everyone knows...", you have failed in your task as an expositor.  Indeed, the fact that the angle sum of a triangle is $180^\circ$ is not obvious, requires some proof, and is not even true without the parallel postulate.  In any event, your "hint" doesn't seem to provide any information which was not already contained in the original question.  The question asked for a proof, and you provided none.